# Grails javascript file reload

Tags: javascript, grails, reload

I'm developing a single page app and this requires a lot of javascript code editing. Unfortunately looks like grails is caching the javascript files and i can't see the effect of the modifications I made until I'm not running a clean command followed by a restart (it is 100% not a browser cache problem).

I'm using the resource plugin to get my JS files but I tried with  and I get the same result, no matter were the files are placed (web-app/js or web-app/assets/js).

The only way to see the modifications in realtime is to place the code in a .gsp file but I don't like this solution. Is there any setting to enable the hot reload?

I'm using grails 2.2.2, win7

Comment: I am able to see my changes by reloading the page with ctrl+f5 in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using resources plugin (as it's the default in grails 2 I think), just add the following to the end of the url and you will se the changes:

```
?_debugResources=y
```

for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/main?_debugResources=y
```

Check the official documentation for other options: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-resources/guide/8.%20Debugging.html

Comment: ...or grails.resources.debug = true in Config.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [Grails cached-resources](http://grails.org/plugin/cached-resources) plugin. This will generate a unique name to your file based on your content, so everytime you change your javascript file, a new name will be linked in your GSP.